# Webmock and hash issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webmock

The error message is this

> WebMock::Response::InvalidBody:
>          must be one of: [Proc, IO, Pathname, String, Array]. 'Hash' given

I am using the code below to test the google library for getting the user info in my controller

```
stub_request(:get, "https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me")
      .to_return(
        body: {email: "test@test.con", name: "Petros"},
        headers: {"Content-Type"=> ["application/json","charset=UTF-8"]}
      )
```

This is the controller code

```
service = auth_with_oauth2_service(calendar_account.get_token)
      response = service.get_userinfo_v2

      calendar_account.user_id = current_user.id
      calendar_account.email = response.email
      calendar_account.name = response.name
```

auth_with_oauth2_service contains this

```
def auth_with_oauth2_service(access_token)

    auth_client = AccessToken.new access_token
    service = Google::Apis::Oauth2V2::Oauth2Service.new
    service.client_options.application_name = "****"

    service.authorization = auth_client

    return service
  end
```

response content form

```
#<Hurley::Response GET https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me == 200 (377 bytes) 647ms>
Success - #<Google::Apis::Oauth2V2::Userinfoplus:0x007ff38df5e820
 @email="****",
 @family_name="Kyriakou",
 @gender="male",
 @given_name="Petros",
 @id="",
 @link="***",
 @locale="en-GB",
 @name="Petros Kyriakou",
 @picture=
  "***",
 @verified_email=true>
```

service being the authorization with google and then request the user data which i can access with response.email and response.name.

However since the google gem gets the info and creates a hash out of it, i cannot do any JSON.parse etc on a string.

What is the way of going about this?

Test suite: Rspec, capybara, webmock, VCR

Comment: I would recommend mocking that service directly, rather than mocking the HTTP call globally. I think you'll have an easier time of it. `allow(my_service).to receive(:my_method).and_return(my_results)`

Comment: @steel hey thanks for your message, however i am not entirely sure how to utilize this, i wrote this, `allow(service).to receive(:get_userinfo_v2).and_return(email: "test@test.com", name: "petros")` but i get undefined local variable or method "service" which kind of makes sense?

Comment: Yeah, it's going to be more like: `allow(Google::Apis::Oauth2V2::Oauth2Service.new).to receive(:get_userinfo_v2).and_return(OpenStruct.new( name: "Petros", email: "test@test.con" ))`

Comment: @JamesMilani hmm getting unauthorized with this

Answer (score 5):

In WebMock, Hash is not accepted as response body. If the response body is json, You need to encode your hash as json:

```
{ email: "test@test.con", name: "Petros" }.to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Following up on Steel's comment, if you're going to use the stub method, then you are going to need to chain the stubs. You can give this a try:

```
service = Object.new
allow(Google::Apis::Oauth2V2::Oauth2Service).to receive(:new).and_return(service)
allow(service).to receive(:get_userinfo_v2).and_return(OpenStruct.new( name: "Petros", email: "test@test.con" ))
```

This makes what's happening fairly explicit.

Comment: hey `.to_json` cleared the error but now i get `undefined method 'email' for nil:NilClass` i suppose it has something to do with the service, needs to be stubbed as well? i added more code please see `auth_with_oauth2_service`

Comment: Yeah, I guess in your controller `response` is now nil, and it's calling `.email` on it. Hmmmmm. I'll keep thinking on it.

Comment: Can you log the `response` object on a successful call and post what that object is in the question? Thanks!

Comment: Hey sure jsut added the response!

Comment: I updated my edit. I'm curious what you think about that approach.

Comment: hey still doesn't work `WebMock::Response::InvalidBody:
       must be one of: [Proc, IO, Pathname, String, Array]. 'OpenStruct' given`

Comment: Shoot, just figured out testing it myself, and that doesn't work either.